# Alternative to GLUTesselator?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I was wondering if there was a library or another way to produce multi contour polygons in OpenGL. I did code profiling and the GLUTesselator is killing my loop. Thanks

---

**Bounty**
+50 for a library with a GPL-compatible license, and ideally 3D (second best would be 2.5D like GLUtesselator itself.)

Comment: Is your geometry static?

Comment: @finnw: Do you mean 3D as in polygons in general position in R^3 but with coplanar vertices, or full-on random-ish 3D point cloud?

Comment: @genpfault, all triangular faces (though it would be nice to have an 'internal edge' flag like GLUtesselator has, allowing for non-triangular faces to be transformed to triangle fans.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's always [GPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPC_General_Polygon_Clipper_Library).

**EDIT**: Some others:

Flipcode [mystery triangulator](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Efficient_Polygon_Triangulation.shtml).  Slower than GPC in my extremely limited, probably wrong tests.

[poly2tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) is BSD-licensed.

**EDIT2**: [Earcut.hpp](https://github.com/mapbox/earcut.hpp) is now a thing.

Comment: The Flipcode "mystery triangulator" doesn't support holes or, presumably, self-intersecting (complex) polygons. There's an article here describing some fixes to it (but I doubt that'll work either because this is a **hard** problem). http://www.nicolaslelong.fr/2008_03_01_archive.html

Answer (score 1):

For whatever's worth, the SGI Free License B 2.0 is now GPL-compatible, being essentially identical to the X11 license, according to the GNU project:

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#SGIFreeB

http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#X11License

The SGI Free License B 2.0 is the license under which the GLU tessellator in GLU 9.0.0 has been released:

ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/glu/

So go ahead and use the GLU tessellator in your GPL project!

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) and [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the multi contour part, but I think if you want the graphic card to do the hard work of drawing polygons you might want to look a [Stencil Buffer](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13).

Comment: No, the CPU needs to know the resulting geometry (in the form of triangles.)